# Pinterest button on hover positioning

Tags: html, css, pinterest

I'm trying to add a Pin it button that appears on hover on images on my website, but the positioning is totally wrong.

Basically the button's position is calculated relative to the window, and it will always stay at the initial distance from top of the window.

You can see what is happening by entering [here](http://cowgoesmoo.com/blog).

I've tried adding position relative to the images, but it won't help. My guess is that the problem comes from the fact that my pages are positioned absolute.

Comment: Is your link correct?

It redirected me to some blog site...

Comment: could you please fill a jsfiddle or put some code on the question instread of giving a page that will no longer exist in few hours? Thanks

Comment: On that 'page that will no longer exist in a few hours', which is a wrong statement by the way, if you scroll down you will see an image. If you hover on that image, you will see a Pinterest button appearing at the bottom of the screen, and then you will understand my problem.